# pykakasiでローマ字変換したリストをCSVファイルにするには？

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pykakasi

pykakasiで日本語をローマ字に変換した場合、再度CSVファイルで取り出すにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？ご助言頂けますと幸いです。

**エラー**

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

**コード**

```
G=nx.Graph()
df=pd.read_csv("at1.csv",header=None)
df

from pykakasi import kakasi
text = df
kakasi = kakasi()  

kakasi.setMode("H", "a")  
kakasi.setMode("K", "a")  
kakasi.setMode("J", "a")  

kakasi.setMode("r", "Hepburn") 
conv = kakasi.getConverter()
result = conv.do(text)
# print(result)

df=pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Comment: `at1.csv`ファイルの構造や内容を追記してみてください。csvにしたりpandasを使う必要があるほど複雑なデータでしょうか？ 逆にその場合はpykakasiのConverterのパラメータにpandas DataFrameをそのまま渡せないのでは？ [Programming Interface](https://pykakasi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#api-documents-ref), [漢字仮名混じり文をローマ字に変換](http://blog.serverworks.co.jp/tech/2019/12/16/post-73777/) ドキュメントでは単純な文字列をパラメータとして渡しているようですが。

Comment: @maruchanz このエラーは、`df=pd.DataFrame(result)` の行で起こっているということで良いでしょうか？（そのような情報も含まれているので、可能であればエラーメッセージを全て載せていただけると嬉しいです）

Comment: 1年前の記事で現象も違うのですが「1回の呼び出しでは出来ません」のようです。[pykakasiでcsvの値をローマ字変換してエクスポートしたい](https://teratail.com/questions/175014) いったん単純な文字列に分解して呼び出し、結果を組み合わせて CSV にする必要がありそうです。

Comment: kunifさん　ご回答有難うございます。そもそもローマ字ファイルにする必要がなくなったので、この質問はご放念頂いてもかまいません。お手数おかけして申し訳ございません。

Comment: nekketsuuさん いつもありがとうございます。こちらの質問はそもそもローマ字ファイルにする必要がなくなりましたので、ご放念頂いて構いません。折角コメント頂いた手前、申し訳ございません。